# How do I upload a file to Google Colaboratory that is already on Google Drive?

Tags: file-upload, google-colaboratory

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=KHeruhacFpSU

In this notebook help it explains how to upload a file to drive and then download to Colaboratory but my files are already in drive.

Where can I find the file ID ?

```
# Download the file we just uploaded.
#
# Replace the assignment below with your file ID
# to download a different file.
#
# A file ID looks like: 1uBtlaggVyWshwcyP6kEI-y_W3P8D26sz
file_id = 'target_file_id'
```

Comment: You can check the id of the file in the sharable link for that file.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use pydrive for this ([docs](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filelist.html)).

You could also do this via the Drive UI -- I think the shortest path is to select the file, click "Get shareable link" -- it's the `id` parameter in the resulting URL. (If the file wasn't shared when you started, you'll want to then uncheck the green "link" button.)

Answer (score 0):

### Connect to Gdrive using below snippet.

You will have to authenticate twice using the link from cell output. But once this step is taken care of you can load files from drive and save to drive directly as you would do locally.

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}

!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

### Read CSV using pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('drive/path/file.csv')
```

### Save CSV

Use index = False if you don't need index as first col in csv.

```
df.to_csv('drive/path/file.csv',index = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use curlWget extension in chrome. If you want to download anything, just click on download and as soon as it started downloading you can cancel the download. Go to curlwget and get the whole link of file or data, just copy it.
Go to colab, add a cell and paste it, just put ! mark before the copied data from curlwget.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use colab api

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```